# AVAudioRecorder record AAC/m4a

Tags: ios, ipad, audio, xamarin.ios, avaudiorecorder

I am trying to record audio on the Device using AVAudioRecorder. That file is transmitted to a web server and I want to play that resulting file in a web browser..

I have tried various combinations of settings on the device...nothing seems to encode the file into the correct AAC format.

QuickTime says that it doesn't know how to play this file.

Sample code

```
    private void InitializeRecordingSession() {
         string fileName = string.Format("{0}.m4a", Guid.NewGuid());
         string tmpdir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + "/audio";
          if (!Directory.Exists(tmpdir))
               Directory.CreateDirectory(tmpdir);
          audioFilePath = Path.Combine(tmpdir, fileName);

          Console.WriteLine("Audio File Path: " + audioFilePath);

          var url = NSUrl.FromFilename(audioFilePath);
          var settings = new AVAudioRecorderSettings() {
               AudioFormat = AudioFormatType.MPEG4AAC,
               SampleRate = 44100,
               NumberChannels = 1,
               AudioQuality = AVAudioQuality.High,    
          };

          recorder = AVAudioRecorder.ToUrl(url, settings, out error);

          //Set Recorder to Prepare To Record
          recorder.PrepareToRecord();  
     }
```

**Edit**-By putting this code in before the line

```
recorder = AVAudioRecorder.ToUrl(url, settings, out error);
```

Everything worked.

```
NSError error;    
AVAudioSession audioSession = AVAudioSession.SharedInstance();
audioSession.SetCategory(AVAudioSession.CategoryRecord, out error);
audioSession.SetActive(true, out error);
```

Comment: I'm wondering if you've found the solution to this as I faced the same problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The iOS SDK is apparently stupid. Setting the format ID key to `kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC` is not enough for it to actually encode the file; in QuickTime it will play but in its properties you'll just see `AAC` and no further details. Changing the output file extension to `m4a` should help do the trick and make it apply the right encoding.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I tried that and it didn't work. But i'll try it again.

Comment: this still isn't working "This is not a file that quicktime understands"

Comment: I had to add this before I started recording for the resultant .m4a file to be usable.
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil];
[session setActive:YES error:nil];`

Comment: This is unbelievable, tried to find the problem for days. If you play a file with the wrong encoding because of the mentioned file ending problem it works on iOS but not Android and a few players. There is no way to see that there is a problem with your file until you get it away from iOS. Thanks so much.

Comment: This answer is correct. When you save the recorded file, you must add the "aac" extension in the URL for it to save as aac file compatible with Android and Windows devices. If you dont include any extension on the file name, it will put the file inside CAF container, which is apple proprietary.

Answer (score 34):

For hardware-accelerated encoders, only one session can be active at any given time. This means that, for AAC, it will work in the simulator (where a software encoder is used) but might fail on the device (where a hardware encoder is used) unless your app activates the `AVAudioSession`.

I also was attempting to use AVAudioRecorder to record audio in an AAC encoded format preferably in a .m4a file.  I had a beast of a time doing this.  I was quickly able to get the code to record to AAC inside of a core audio file (.caf), but I couldn't get AVAudioRecorder to properly format a .m4a.  I was just about to rewrite the recording code in my application using the lower level Audio Units API but instead I put that on the back burner and added in the code to handle the shared audio session.  Once that was set up, I went back and tried to save as an .m4a and it just worked.

Here is some example code:

```
NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSURL *tmpFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tmp.m4a"]];
NSDictionary *recordSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC], AVFormatIDKey,
                        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:16000.0], AVSampleRateKey,
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                        nil];
NSError *error = nil;
AVAudioRecorder *recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:tmpFileUrl settings:recordSettings error:&error];
[recorder prepareToRecord];

AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil];
[session setActive:YES error:nil];

[recorder record];
```

Then to end the recording I used:

```
[recorder stop];
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
int flags = AVAudioSessionSetActiveFlags_NotifyOthersOnDeactivation;
[session setActive:NO withFlags:flags error:nil];
```

Then the file at 'tmpFileUrl' can be used as you please.

Comment: Amazing answer. Thanks this saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 3):

The hints about `AVAudioSession` are very helpful!

Since `setActive:withFlags:error:` has become deprecated in iOS 6.0
the code for stopping audio session should be adjusted to:

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
int flags = AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation;
[session setActive:NO withOptions:flags error:nil];
```