# How can I get best results recording iPhone system Audio?

Tags: iphone, audio, recording

I'm looking for the xCode to record system audio on the iPhone directly into an m4a file. Specifically, I'd like to record an audio file playing on the device and input from the mic at the same time. I understand there is the risk of picking up other audio events and would want to pause or stop my recording (for example, I receive a text and there is a chime.... Would want to stop the record)..

Answer (score 1):

You can use **AVAudioRecorder**

Below code taken from [techotopia.com](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Recording_Audio_on_an_iPhone_with_AVAudioRecorder_%28iOS_6%29)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface RecordViewController : UIViewController
        <AVAudioRecorderDelegate, AVAudioPlayerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioRecorder *audioRecorder;
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *recordButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *playButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *stopButton;
- (IBAction)recordAudio:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)playAudio:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)stop:(id)sender;

@end
```

**Creating the AVAudioRecorder Instance**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   _playButton.enabled = NO;
   _stopButton.enabled = NO;

   NSArray *dirPaths;
   NSString *docsDir;

   dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
        NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   docsDir = dirPaths[0];

    NSString *soundFilePath = [docsDir
       stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.caf"];

   NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

   NSDictionary *recordSettings = [NSDictionary
            dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
            [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin],
            AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
            [NSNumber numberWithInt:16],
            AVEncoderBitRateKey,
            [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2],
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0],
            AVSampleRateKey,
            nil];

  NSError *error = nil;

  _audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]
                  initWithURL:soundFileURL
                  settings:recordSettings
                  error:&error];

   if (error)
   {
           NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
   } else {
           [_audioRecorder prepareToRecord];
   }
}
```

**Implementing the Action Methods** 
    - (IBAction)recordAudio:(id)sender {
         if (!_audioRecorder.recording)
         {
                 _playButton.enabled = NO;
                 _stopButton.enabled = YES;
                 [_audioRecorder record];
         }
    }

```
- (IBAction)playAudio:(id)sender {
    if (!_audioRecorder.recording)
    {
       _stopButton.enabled = YES;
       _recordButton.enabled = NO;

        NSError *error;

        _audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
        initWithContentsOfURL:_audioRecorder.url
        error:&error];

        _audioPlayer.delegate = self;

        if (error)
              NSLog(@"Error: %@",
              [error localizedDescription]);
        else
              [_audioPlayer play];
   }
}

- (IBAction)stop:(id)sender {
    _stopButton.enabled = NO;
    _playButton.enabled = YES;
    _recordButton.enabled = YES;

    if (_audioRecorder.recording)
    {
            [_audioRecorder stop];
    } else if (_audioPlayer.playing) {
            [_audioPlayer stop];
    }
}
```

**Implementing the Delegate Methods**

```
-(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:
(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
        _recordButton.enabled = YES;
        _stopButton.enabled = NO;
}

-(void)audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur:
(AVAudioPlayer *)player 
error:(NSError *)error
{
        NSLog(@"Decode Error occurred");
}

-(void)audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:
(AVAudioRecorder *)recorder 
successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
}

-(void)audioRecorderEncodeErrorDidOccur:
(AVAudioRecorder *)recorder 
error:(NSError *)error
{
        NSLog(@"Encode Error occurred");
}
```

You can see the details [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Recording_Audio_on_an_iPhone_with_AVAudioRecorder_%28iOS_6%29)

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried to record audio from both the mic and from streaming audio at the same time, however I noticed the previous answer was recording to a .caf file instead of a .m4a and that it did not set up the AVAudioSession, so I thought I would provide this link to a similar question I answered previously:

[AVAudioRecorder record AAC/m4a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12163240/avaudiorecorder-record-aac-m4a/12698691#12698691)

Note that setting up the AVAudioSession is what allows other applications (such as the phone app) to grab control of the mic and speaker and pause your app.  In the code I linked to I use a Record session, you probably want to use the Playback and Record session to allow for both activities.  Also, you can handle the notifications described in this doc from apple to handle what happens when your app is interrupted or if control is returned:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html

I know this is not a complete answer, but I hope it helps.